# Get full directory of $file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, readlink

My first shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Input your file"
read $file
path=(readlink -f $file)
echo "$USER, $path" >> scriptlog.txt
```

it said missing operand. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code with this one, and try :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Input your file"
read file
path=$(readlink -f "$file")
echo "$USER, $path" >> scriptlog.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed `$` in line `path=(readlink -f $file)`, the correct one:

```
path=$(readlink -f $file)
```

Also note that, there're many flaws in your script:

- Using `read` without `-r`
- Forgetting double quotes variables

The quick fix:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Input your file"
IFS= read -r file
path=$(readlink -f "$file")
echo "$USER, $path" >> scriptlog.txt
```

Comment: Anh Cường Việt Nam à. nếu được anh team view giúp em nhé. Em cám ơn rất nhiều ạ